# Android Internal Storage And SQLite - How to share data across application without web services?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Can somebody explain the standard for sharing input data between an application without using web services?

For example: A user on Android device 1 input's information to an application about a Location. A user on Android device 2 then launches the same application. What method of storage can be used to ensure that the user of Android device 2 will see the information that was given as input to the application on Android device 1?

From reading about Internal Storage and SQLite I am a bit confused about how to accomplish this without a web service because I am picturing both of these method's of storage being local to the device interacting with them.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's storage is always internal. 
To achieve this you will always need some kind of a web application to synchronise the state across devices.